# Which is better to read files from a directory using PHP - glob() or scandir() or readdir()?

Tags: php, directory

I am a beginner in PHP. I would like to read files from a specific folder / directory. I don't want sub-folders or files in them. I just want to list out direct files inside the directory. I ended up with 3 solutions, `glob()` , `readdir()` , and `scandir()`. I can do file listing like;

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br />";
}
```

and

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: .".$file."<br />";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

and

```
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $val){
  echo $val;
}
```

Which one is faster and more efficient?

Comment: "Which one is faster and gives less head ache to server" this doesn't seem that hard to test yourself.

Comment: Set a timer, run the loops, set a new timer, compare times. Boom: instant answer

Comment: glob() generated in 7.081E-5 seconds.
readdir() generated in 0.00151491 seconds.
scandir() generated in 0.00162292 seconds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe DirectoryIterator from SPL?
http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator($dir_path) as $item) {
   if (!$item->isDot() && $item->isFile()) {
       echo $item->getFilename();
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `isFile` exclude `isDot`? Why do you need to check for both conditions?

Comment: i think you want get the system folder . /..
and you want maybe get any subfolder :) Then you have to recursive iterate this