# How can you use the "*" path wildcard via PHP exec() as part of a `cp` or `ls` command?

Tags: php

I just cannot fathom how to get the PHP `exec()` or `shell_exec()` functions to treat a '*' character as a wildcard. Is there some way to properly encode / escape this character so it makes it through to the shell?

This is on windows (via CLI shell script if that matters, Terminal or a git-bash yields the same results).

Take the following scenario:
`C:\temp\` contains a bunch of png images.

```
echo exec('ls C:\temp\*');
// output: ls: cannot access 'C:\temp\*': No such file or directory
```

Permissions is not the problem:

```
echo exec('ls C:\temp\exmaple.png');
// output: C:\temp\example.png
```

Therefore the `*` character is the problem and is being treated as a literal filename rather than a wildcard. The file named `*` does not exist, so from that point of view, it's not wrong...

It also does not matter if I use double quotes to encase the command:

```
echo exec("ls C:\temp\*");
// output: ls: cannot access 'C:\temp\*': No such file or directory
```

I have also tried other things like:

```
exec(escapeshellcmd('ls C:\temp\*'));
exec('ls C:\temp\\\*');
exec('ls "C:\temp\*"');
exec('ls "C:\temp\"*');
```

And nothing works...

I'm pretty confused that I cannot find any other posts discussing this but maybe I'm just missing it. At this point I have already worked around the issue by manually programming a glob loop and using the internal `copy()` function on each file individually, but it's really bugging me that I do not understand how to make the wildcard work via shell command.

EDIT:
Thanks to @0stone0 - The answer provided did not particularly answer my initial question but I had not tried using forward slashes in the path and when I do:

`exec('ls C:/temp/*')`

It works correctly, and as 0stone0 said, it only returns the last line of the output, which is fine since this was just for proof of concept as I was not actually attempting to parse the output.

Also, on a side note, since posting this question my system had been updated to Win11 22H2 and now for some reason the original test code (with the backslashes) no longer returns the "Cannot access / no file" error message. Instead it just returns an empty string and has no output set to the `&$output` parameter either. That being said, I'm not sure if the forward slashes would have worked on my system prior to the 22H2 update.

Comment: `ls` is generally a Unix/Linux command, which is not recognized in Windows. The fact that you're using `C:\...` implies you're using a Windows OS. Have you tried `dir` instead of `ls`? Better yet, have you tried PHP's [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or [`scandir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) functions? Also, see [Which is better to read files from a directory using PHP - glob() or scandir() or readdir()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290498/which-is-better-to-read-files-from-a-directory-using-php-glob-or-scandir-o)

Comment: I'm on windows 11 so LS is supported. As I showed in the example code, the ls command works just fine if I provide the full file path rather than the "*" wildcard in place of the file name at the path in question. I also explained that I already worked around the issue using `glob()` and `copy()` internal to PHP but I am trying to learn / understand why I cannot use a wildcard inside an `exec()` call like I can directly on the shell...

Comment: Forget about `ls` and wildcards. Use the PHP function [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

Comment: The output of `ls` has been designed for human consumption. It is not recommended for scripting because the format of the output is not the same for all Un*x flavours, because the way it handles the special characters and for several other reasons.

Comment: The use of `ls` in the example is only to demonstrate the issue. Try not to make assumption about what I am doing beyond the specifics of my question. This was spurred by the fact that I was simply trying to run `cp /path/to/dir/* /path/to/new/dir/` and it was failing due to the `*` being present. Running a single shell command to move a bunch of files is more optimal for my time than in the context of the script I was writing, than invoking `glob()` and writing extra lines for the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec()` only returns the **last output line** by default.

The wildcard probably works, but the output is just truncated.

---

Pass an variable by ref to `exec()` and log that:

```php
<?php
    $output = [];
    exec('ls -lta /tmp/*', $output);
    var_dump($output);
```

Without any additional changes, this returns the same as when I run `ls -lta /tmp/*` in my Bash terminal

---

That said, `glob()` is still the preferred way of getting data like this especcially since
[You shouldn't *parse* the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: The output of `ls` has been designed for human consumption, not for scripting. It does not use the same format across all Un*x flavours. `find` is recommended for scripting.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it tipped me off to try forward slashes in the path which does work. Though see my edit on my question for more on this as I'm not sure how much of this working now has to do with my 22H2 update.